# How to export whole layer/all shapes to single SVG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm working on this simple icon. I used the shape tool to make it:

[image]

If I right click the layer and click "Export As..." or use File > Export > Export As, it shows this:

[image]

Looks like maybe it's only trying to export 1 of the 6 rectangles. If I save it out, it looks the same.

I want the whole image, with the padding around the edges and everything. How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you using Photoshop to make SVGs?  Use a vector image editor like Illustrator or Inkscape (which is free and Open Source). Forget Photoshop - it's not the right kind of software.

Comment: @Billy because I'm a n00b and I only know photoshop. Don't want to learn a new app if I don't have to. It's only a few simple icons I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your process is correct-

The "Export As" screenshot shows the export at 32 px x 32 px  viewed at 100%- the "Document" screenshot shows the entire file (all 6 rectangles) at 32 px x 32 px but viewed at 3200%.

Try and increase the view size at the bottom of the "Export As" dialog and you should see that the entire document is there.

---

EDIT- OK just looked deeper into your screenshots. It appears that your shapes have a black fill *and a black stroke*- The stroke is 25 px and this is the issue. I re-created your shapes with a black fill and no stroke and the svg worked fine. Change the black stroke to 0 px and set its color to none- (The red circled boxes circled in the screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Do you mean where it says "100%" at the bottom of the export dialog? That just zooms it in/out. The weird black/white circle next to it which conveniently doesn't have a tooltip doesn't do much either. Scaling the image on the right or left doesn't help either.

Comment: Yes- on the bottom is the scaling for the "View"- the scaling on the left and right is for scaling your output (your export)- I just think the "View" scaling is so small you cannot see the entire 32 px document. Try hitting the + button  on the bottom where it says 100%.

Comment: Yeah, I did. I tried all those options. None work. And I did save the image to disk too and previewed in another program. Still not coming out right.

Comment: edited (added to) my answer just now.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!!